# How can I have Android automatically connect to a VPN only when on an unsecured WiFi Network?

Tags: vpn

Let's say I want to connect to a WiFi hotspot, but it is unsecured. I'd like to connect to a VPN server, but only if I'm on an unsecured WiFi network. If I'm on a secured network or data, I'd like it to stay in VPN off mode.

Comment: Have you looked into [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)?

Comment: Please clarify... Do you know the set of wifi y you want to connect to or are looking at a solution that first determines if the network is open or not  and then act accordingly

Answer (score 2):

I don't think any app can do this, given that you want to run another app or script to connect to a vpn based on conditions of open/secure WiFi

Hence, you need to look at automation, I prefer [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) ,being easier to learn-that's why I use it :-), and free version offering creation of upto 5 macros.

Coming to the solution, approach is based on this logic

1. Connect to an open network only if not connected to secure network.
2. You have a list of open networks to start with, which can be manually updated. Detection of a new open network and dynamically updating list of open newtworks is creating complexity , since you may not want to connect to any available open network for reasons like- how long it permits your session, ease of logging into it, stability, speed amongst others.
3. You have an app of your choice to create a VPN connection.

The macro would look like this.  I have tested only once , since there are no open networks around where I live.  The app used for creating VPN was [VyprVPN](https://www.goldenfrog.com/vyprvpn). That is the app site link. My PS is not connecting to give you PS link . This app also gives you option of connecting to untrusted networks automatically, once you enter the network name. Connection beyond a limit is subscription based.

**Trigger**

WiFi enabled (macro will only trigger if any WiFi is connected)

**Actions**

Wifi connect to network> configure> connect to network> select all open networks from the list ( you have connected to these in the past and show up on your cell)

Wait 30 Sec (wait before next action, configurable)

Launch Application . From the drop down menu choose preferred app to create VPN

**Constraints**

WiFi State > not connected to network> from list choose all secure networks

The macro gets triggered only when WiFi is enabled, and actions executed only when the constraint is TRUE, meaning you are not connected to any securenetwork. It then connects you to open WiFi from the list of open networks and after a pause launches the application to create a VPN

This is the skeleton macro and can be tweaked for optimal performance after testing and you may like to add additional things like sounding an alarm, announcing that you are connected to open network, popping up a notification etc.

Hope this solves...all the best